# Scrape the text inside a script tag using jsoup on a website

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the data inside a js script from a website, using Jsoup.

The script is located in the header, which looks like :

```
<head>
  <script1>
    function
  </script1>
  <link>
  <script2>
     var = someJsonData
  </script2>
</head>
```

The only thing that I want to obtain is the string "var = someJsonData", in the second script.

Because it seems that this script is always (or almost) located at the end of the head tag, I use this to access it :

```
String page = client.get("https://mywebsite.fr);
Element strScript = Jsoup.parse(page).select("head > script").last();
```

By using this code, I can retrieve the last script, in which I am interested, but I get this :

```
<script>
   var = someJsonData;
</script>
```

meanwhile I just want :

```
var = someJsonData
```

Is there a simple way to do it or do I have to parse it manually using some function ?

Is there a better way to get the last script than using the Jsoup last function ? (the script is the only one which contains the string "window.datalayer") ?

Thanks  !

Comment: Did you see all the ***French News Comments*** from your previous question about this?  Here, if the ***JSoup*** package isn't working for you, why don't you just use a ***plain-old-vanilla*** `html.substring, html.indexOf("<SCRIPT")` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use strScript.data() to get the script content.

For your reference https://simplesolution.dev/java-jsoup-extract-javascript-from-script-element/